# Does $\inf_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}g=\inf_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}g_{0}$ imply $\inf_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}ge^{|x|^{2}}=\inf_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}g_{0}e^{|x|^{2}}$?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $g,g_{0}:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to \mathbb{R}$ be nonnegative bounded smooth functions s.t. $\inf\limits_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}g=\inf\limits_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}g_{0}$ then do we have

$\inf\limits_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}ge^{|x|^{2}}=\inf\limits_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}g_{0}e^{|x|^{2}}$?

any obvious counterexamples?

Because $e^{|x|^{2}}>1$ and $g,g_{0}\geq 0$, the infimum of both can only go up.
The context is heat equation and maximum principle. In that context I should have written instead 
$\inf\limits_{\mathbb{R}^{n}\times [0,T]}ge^{|x|^{2}}=\inf\limits_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}g_{0}e^{|x|^{2}}$.

In a sense I fixed level set i.e. $\inf\limits_{\mathbb{R}^{n}\times \{t=r\}}ge^{|x|^{2}}=\inf\limits_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}g_{0}e^{|x|^{2}}$.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true. Take any pair of smooth, bounded and non-negative functions $g$ and $g_0$  with $\inf g = \inf g_0 = G$ such that $g(0) = G$ and $g_0(0) \neq G$. Then $\inf_x g(x) e^{|x|^2} = g(0) e^0 = G$ but $\inf_x g_0(x) e^{|x|^2} > G$.

To see the latter consider a sequence $(x_k)$ s.t. $g_0(x_k) e^{|x_k|^2} \to \inf_x g_0(x) e^{|x|^2}$. By contradiction assume that the infimum is $G$. If $x_k \not\to 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ s.t. there is a subsequence $(x_{k'})$ with $|x_{k'}| > \delta$ for all $k'$ and hence $g(x_{k'}) e^{|x_{k'}|^2} > g(x_{k'}) e^{\delta^2} > g(x_{k'}) (1+\delta^2) \geq G (1 + \delta^2)$, which contradicts $g_0(x_k) e^{|x_k|^2} \to G$. If $x_k \to 0$ we have, by continuity of $g_0$, $g_0(0) = G$, another contradiction.